# Visual Studio 2010 randomly says the command line changed, and rebuilds

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, rebuild

Visual Studio sometimes decides to rebuild my entire huge project because of one small change.  I turned build logging up to Diagnostic to see what was the problem, and here's what I'm seeing:

```
< Bunch of spam >
Outputs for C:\<snip>\PRECOMPILEDHEADERS.CPP:
    C:\<snip>\PRECOMPILEDHEADERS.OBJ
All outputs are up-to-date.
Forcing rebuild of all source files due to a change in the command line
```

... and then it rebuilds my precompiled headers, then everything else.

This happens when I change a single .cpp or .h file inside the project.  I'm not changing anything in the project settings.  It also doesn't happen all the time for the same change; it's random.

Any ideas on what's going on here?  Where can I get more information?  I tried enabling debugging via the description in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/21/enable-c-project-system-logging.aspx but it didn't give any more information.  I can't figure out where this "Forcing rebuild of all source files due to a change in the command line" is coming from.  It's not in any of the factory MSBuild files.

Some other info: it's a C++/CLI dll project that links a lot of other projects, including C#, native c++, and other C++/CLI dll's.  I tried removing all the C# projects from the dependencies since those tend to cause problems, but that didn't change it.  I've googled that specific string, but my situation doesn't match that of any of the other people reporting it. (One was using Intel C++, another was MSBuild from the command line and changing the case.  I'm hitting build solution from within Visual Studio itself).

Edit to explain common fixes I've tried:

I've tried building only the project.  Does the same thing.

I'm not including any .h files that don't exist.

I've deleted the bin/object folders and rebuilt from scratch.  This usually makes it go away for a couple builds, but then it comes right back.

Edit #2:

Found something suspicious earlier in the log:

```
3>Using "ResolveNonMSBuildProjectOutput" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
3>Task "ResolveNonMSBuildProjectOutput"
3>  Resolving project reference "..\..\..\..\CommonCore\VS2010\Project1\Project1.vcxproj".
3>  Project reference "..\..\..\..\CommonCore\VS2010\Project1\Project1.vcxproj" has not been resolved.
```

This is repeated for several of my projects...  I'm gonna chase that down and see if maybe it's a problem with the project reference hint paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did three things, and the problem seems to have gone away.  I'm trying to narrow it down a little but I figured I'd go ahead and post them:

- Deleted and re-added all the references and project references
- Fixed one of my projects that wasn't setting the .NET framework target to 3.5 to match the rest of my solution (I was getting away with it because the project didn't use .NET anyway)
- Set "Copy Local Satellite Assemblies" to false for all references including System ones.

Beware that some or all of this stuff might be voodoo...

Comment: I apologize to any practitioners of Voodoo who were offended by my metaphor.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it's an old thread, but I encountered the same problem recently.
My solution was to disable the precompiled headers - now a simple change in one sourcefile won't lead into a "rebuild" any more.

Comment: Yes, that definitely fixes it :)  We can't quite live without the precompiled headers or our stuff builds too slow, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem with Visual Studio 2012 recently. I'm on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012 Professional (2012.2) building C++ projects. It's worth noting that I recently migrated the solution from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2012.

One of the C++ projects (an executable with a DLL project as a reference) was rebuilding every time one of its compilation units was changed, e.g. simply saving main.cpp would cause all compilation units (including the pre-compiled header) to rebuild. I spotted the the following message in the build logs:

```
Forcing rebuild of all source files due to a change in the command line since the last build.
```

I turned build log file verbosity to **Diagnostic** (*Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run*) and compared the log files from a clean build and a build after one compilation unit has been changed (which forced a full rebuild). I noticed that:

- "**Path**" had changed from one build to the next ("*;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\VsGraphics*" seems to have been tacked on the end)
- there was a difference in **TaskTracker.exe** command lines to do with **CancelEvents**
- there was a warning about **OutputPath** not being set

I pulled my hair out.

I eventually resorted to recreating the offending project from scratch rather than relying on the project that was automatically generated during the migration process from 2008 to 2012. It seems to be behaving as expected now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  I haven't run into the problem with vs2012 *yet* but we'll see... :)